# I don't know how to create a changeable text for a reusable component in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I was creating a reusable tabs component by watching tutorial. Having watched it, I figured out how it works. But, as for my project, I need to create tabs with heading containing a title that can be changed because this is a reusable component, so I have to change each heading's title for each new tab, but I haven't figured out how to do it. I need somehow to get title from component TabsWrapper that I added to my page

```
    <div class="tab_header">{{title}}</div>
```

and then make this title change a text inside this div that is the main header of a TabsWrapper component.

```
   <div class="tab_header">{{title}}</div>
```

My code:
The first one is the code out of component that I added to my homepage of the website.

```
<TabsWrapper>
      <Tab title="Tab 1">Hello 1</Tab>
      <Tab title="Tab 2">Hello 2 </Tab>
      <Tab title="Tab 3">Hello 3</Tab>
      <Tab title="Tab 4">Hello 4</Tab>
    </TabsWrapper>
```

The second one is the code inside the component that is responsible for TabsWrapper

```
<template>

  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab_header"></div>
    <ul class="tabs_header">
      <li 
      v-for="title in tabTitles" 
      :key="title"
      @click="selectedTitle = title"
      :class=" {selected: title ==selectedTitle}"
      >

        {{ title }}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { ref} from 'vue';
import { provide } from 'vue';
export default{
    setup(props,{slots}){
        const tabTitles=ref(slots.default().map((tab)=> tab.props.title))
        const selectedTitle=ref(tabTitles.value[0])

        provide("selectedTitle", selectedTitle)

        return{
            selectedTitle,
            tabTitles,
            
        
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

This chunk of code takes each title from Tab

```
      <Tab title="Tab 1">Hello 1</Tab>
```

And this chunk of code renders it out

```
 <li 
      v-for="title in tabTitles" 
      :key="title"
      @click="selectedTitle = title"
      :class=" {selected: title ==selectedTitle}"
      >

        {{ title }}
      </li>
```

I've tried to repeat the same technique, but it worked out, but I think that there's the better way to do it

```html
 <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab_header" v-for="headtitle in headTitles" :key="headtitle">{{headtitle}}</div>
    <ul class="tabs_header">
      <li 
      v-for="title in tabTitles" 
      :key="title"
      @click="selectedTitle = title"
      :class=" {selected: title ==selectedTitle}"
      >

        {{ title }}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { ref} from 'vue';
import { provide } from 'vue';
export default{
    setup(props,{slots}){
        const tabTitles=ref(slots.default().map((tab)=> tab.props.title))
        const headTitles=ref(slots.default().map((tab)=>tab.props.headtitle))
        const selectedTitle=ref(tabTitles.value[0])

        provide("selectedTitle", selectedTitle)

        return{
            selectedTitle,
            tabTitles,
            headTitles,
            
        
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass props in the script tag and directly access them using this keyword and prop name.

```
export default {
  props: ['foo'],
  created() {
    // props are exposed on `this`
    console.log(this.foo)
  }
}
```

In the template tag like this

```
<span>{{ foo }}</span>
```

you don't need to use ref you can directly use v-for and loop over the array elements.

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in foo">
  {{item}}
</li>
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Even though I'm just learning Vue.Js, i'm trying to take advantage of reusable components because they're the best way to speed up coding process.